# Create a vim instance from a python class?

Tags: python, vim

I'm calling a python function that returns a dictionary, and that works but I was just wondering if there was a way to create an instance like this in vimscript `m.multi(3), m.div(20,5)`. This is just an example, not sure about the last 2 lines.

```
python3 <<EOF
class Multiply:
    @staticmethod
    def myfunc(n):
        print("Answer is:", n * n)
EOF
python3 m = Multiply
python3 vim.command(f"let multi={m}")
call multi(4)
```

Comment: @Barmar ok I guess it's not possible then..? I will just stay with calling a function 90 times for 3 calendar months. Which is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, leave object oriented stuff in python code.

Answer (score 0):

Define `Multi` as a VimScript function and call python inside it:

```
python3 <<EOF
import vim

class Multiply:
    @staticmethod
    def myfunc(n):
        print("Answer is:", n * n)
EOF

" Single global instance
python3 m = Multiply()

function! Multi(i)
    " int() is required as vim.eval() returns a string even for int arg
    python3 m.myfunc(int(vim.eval('a:i')))
endfunction
```

Test: `:call Multi(4)`

Comment: That seems to work but you're still having to call the python function every time you call Multi(4) ? So if Multi() gets called 2000 times, you also call python 2000 times ? Unless python would somehow be a constructor function for vim which sounds complicated. An instance does not call the function....or does it? How would you add 7 other methods ? Create 7 different functions ?

Comment: @ritchie "*That seems to work but you're still having to call the python function every time you call Multi(4) ? So if Multi() gets called 2000 times, you also call python 2000 times ?*" Alas, yes. "*Unless python would somehow be a constructor function for vim ...?*" I don't think it's possible. "*How would you add 7 other methods ? Create 7 different functions ?*" Yes. Or create one VimScript function that route it calls to Python; something like `:call Route('multi', 4)`; `Route` should use `getattr(m, func_name)(*args)`

Comment: I think what I'm asking is not possible, I could be wrong. For now I'm just returning a dictionary from the python function which works fine. I don't think it's possible to have in vimscript ```Cal.weekday(2021,1,27) Cal.days_in_month(2021,1,27)```. It's too complex to get all the info I need with pure vimscript for example just to get the day I had to do this.. ```let day_name = strftime('%A', strptime('%m %d %Y',  month . ' ' . day . ' ' . year ))```.